# Select in js not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to js and using selective for the first time. Please be kind. I know this is a very silly doubt but I cant get it work.

I am having the below code to create drop-down list and to have search through it -

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../select2-3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../select2-3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#mySelect").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
</script>
</body>
</html>

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="dateRange" id="mySelect" size="1">
           <option value > Select Country </option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                <option value="Heard Island">Heard Island</option>
                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See</option>
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="Saint Barthelemy">Saint Barthelemy</option>
                <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                <option value="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    </select> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

the code does not seems to work.
what is that I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You need to include jQuery before you're able to call `$()` functions

Comment: You did not include jQuery library. Also why are there two independant <html> blocks ... ?

Comment: @MackieeE - have update the question after including jquery too.
Still it doesnt work

Comment: @Imperative - even after including jquery it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate html documents there and your head and body tags are whack. Also your jQuery selector is wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../select2-3.4.8/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="../select2-3.4.8/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#mySelect").select2(); });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="dateRange" id="mySelect" size="1">
           <option value > Select Country </option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                <option value="Heard Island">Heard Island</option>
                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See</option>
                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="Saint Barthelemy">Saint Barthelemy</option>
                <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                <option value="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    </select> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can I use the same logic in the case where I have two drop down list in the same page ?

Comment: Sure, you can use both ID's or switch to a class, like this: `<select id="first" class="select2">` and `<select id="second" class="select2">` then `$(document).ready(function() { $(".select2").select2(); });`

Answer (score 1):

`$("mySelect").select2();` should be:

```
$("#mySelect").select2();
```

You should use the prefix of `#` to target an element with a particular id.

And, your html isn't nice.

It should be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title here</title>
    script tags...
  </head>
  <body>
     ... select..
  </body>
</html>
```